# Unable to change the table width

Tags: html, css

[Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwST1.png)

I am trying to create a certificate using HTML and CSS but due to some reason I am not able to change the width of the table...Even though I have set the width of the table but the width of the table is still not changing as you all can see in the above image that table width remain same.

My code:

```
<!Doctype>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    <meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .container {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }

    .l1 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      left: 400px;
    }

    .l2 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      left: 850px;
    }

    .l3 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      left: 270px;
    }
    
      .OC{
      position: absolute;
      top: 40%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .centered {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
     .table {
      position: absolute;
      top: 83%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      width: 100px;
    }
    
    
    
    table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100px;
  
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;    
}

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <img src="l3.jpg" height="800" width="800" class="l3" alt="img3" />
    <img src="l1.jpg" style="align:left" width="100" height="100" class="l1" alt="img1" />
    
    
    
    <img src="l2.png" style="align:right" width="100" height="100" class="l2" alt="img2" /><br/><br/><br/>
    
    <div class="OC">OCCUPANCY CERTIFICATE</div>

    <div class="centered" style="color: lightblue">This is to certify that the building described herein has been inspected and confirms substantially to the approved drawings & to the requirements of all the applicable codes, laws, rules and regulations that were in place at the time of the issue of this certificate.</div>
 
  
  
  <div class="table">
  <table class="table">

  <tr>
    <th>Name of Owner</th>
    <th>Plot Number</th>
    <th colspan="2">Location</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <th>Building Type</th>
    <th>Thram Number</th>
    <th colspan="2">Designated </th>
  </tr>
  
    <tr>
   <th>Flat Type</th>
    <th>Plot  Area</th>
    <th colspan="2">Plot Coverage</th>
  </tr>
  
    <tr>
   <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">Number of Floors</th>
    <th rowspan="2">No. of Units</th>
    <th>Residential </th>
    
  </tr>
  
      <tr> 
    <th>Commercial</th>
  </tr>
  
   <tr>
   <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">Date of final Inspection</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Floor Area</th>
    <th>Residential area</th>
    
  </tr>
  
     <tr> 
    <th>Commercial area</th>
  </tr>
  
   
     <tr> 
    <th colspan="4">Remarks (if any):</th>
  </tr>
  
  
</table>

</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have nested `<stye>` tag which is wrong. `<meta>` tag should not be inside `<style>` tag.

Comment: @Sansui, please, add  a workable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your unable to change table width because parent div.table has width:100px change it and your table width will change.

```
.table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 83%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}
```